# @providesModule throwing error React native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am new to react native 
trying to use @providesModule but no success 
the following is my code
**colors.js**

```
/** 
* @providesModule Colors
*/
const colors = {
   colorPrimary : '#6a1b9a',
   colorPrimaryLight: '#9c4dcc',
  };
 export default colors;
```

I am trying to use the Colors Module in login.js file like

```
import Colors from 'Colors'
```

**Error**

*error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `Colors` from `/Volumes/Acube Data/Anns/Projects/ReactNativeProjects/ColDot/src/components/UserAuth/Login.js`: Module `Colors` does not exist in the Haste module map*

Comment: Have you configured the babel and installed all the necessary dependencies?

Comment: Noi didnt configure babel can u please let me know the dependencies for that

Answer (score 0):

Babel-Cli :

```
npm install --g babel-cli
```

babel-plugin-module-alias:

```
npm install --save babel babel-plugin-module-alias
```

.babelrc in root directory:

```
"babel":{
  "plugins": [[
    "module-alias", [
      { "src": "./app", "expose": "app" },
      { "src": "./app/resources/icon", "expose": "icon" }
      ]
   ]]
```

}

Clear cache :

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Here is a link you can check for example of that : [alias in react native](https://reactnatve.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/alias-in-react-native/#more-550)

Answer (score 0):

They don't work because provideModule overall has been removed as a functionality.
[Removed last traces of @providesModule from React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/eeab57aa26385656cc69f057c9db5c7f4da293ff)

Comment: [Custom Aliases in React Native with Babel](https://www.novis.co/post/custom-aliases-in-react-native-with-babel/)